# How to use Rete Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, rete

How can i use Rete Algorithm in java?

Do i need to write my own algorithm implementation?

Or is there already implemented library available?

Comment: Can you give a link to `rete` algorithm?

Comment: http://www.csl.sri.com/users/mwfong/Technical/RETE%20Match%20Algorithm%20-%20Forgy%20OCR.pdf

Answer (score 5):

So this is a pretty old question, but ranks highly if you're googling for Rete Implementations, so I'll leave some info here.

[The wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) is pretty good and here is a paper about Rete/UL which is according to Doorenbos more efficient than ReteII [Doorenbos, 1995](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1995/CMU-CS-95-113.pdf).

Some Implementations include:

- [Drools](http://www.drools.org/) for java
- [Jess](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/) also java
- [Wongi-Engine](https://github.com/ulfurinn/wongi-engine) for ruby (I use this one) based on the same paper
  as listed above.
- [Ruleby](https://github.com/Ruleby/ruleby) also ruby but defunct
- [Mirmir](https://github.com/hraberg/mimir) clojure
- [Clara Rules](https://github.com/rbrush/clara-rules) also clojure (added 4/20/15)
- [Rete for Triples](https://github.com/rururu/rete) clojure (maybe defunct?)
- [kongra's Rete](https://github.com/kongra/Rete)
  haskell (wow) based on the same paper as listed above.
- [and all of
  these](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rete&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

Its a really useful algorithm if you need to make decisions based on patterns of facts, and as a bonus, you'll have to learn some cool things about graphs and pattern matching.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 4):

A simple Google search for "Rete Algorithm Java" showed up this result (among others): http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines.

The first entry reads: *Drools is an Object-Oriented Rule Engine for Java. Drools is an augmented implementation of Forgy's Rete algorithm tailored for the Java language.*

So the answer seems to be: Yes, there already is a library that implements the algorithm you're looking for.

Comment: do we have the access to the original paper on Rete Algorithm. Somewhere I read that the original paper describes about the implementation in C. Is it possible to access the paper?

Answer (score 0):

See the References section on the Wikipedia entry on the [Rete Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm#References), it contains code snippets in both Pascal and LISP (?) style languages - nothing C-like, though.

Cheers,